# Highcharts min when using categories

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to get the axis of my chart to look like this:

[image]

As you can see the number is above the line and there is a space before the plotbands.

So far I've attempted with the following fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/scpLr1o0/249/

If I use the `min` option such as:

```
min:-0.5
```

the x axis goes crazy with random numbers. So how can I make this indent into my graph?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, you need to set the tickLength of the yAxis.

```
yAxis: {
      gridLineWidth: 2,
      tickWidth: 2,
      tickLength: 20,
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jL8ybr3p/

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickLength